# Can't read incoming SMS messages with AT+CMGL=ALL

Tags: php, sms

I am using a PHP's Digital_IO to connect with a usb connected modem, I have been using a Digi Xbee LTE. I have it working great to send SMS messages, but can't find how to pull up the list of incoming messages.

This seems like a no-brainer, I have read a dozen tutorials like this one: http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToReceiveSMSUsingPC.asp#11.1 and they all point me back to AT+CMGL, which doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here is a console log. Near the end you can see a MSG (+CMT: "4805554667") I sent from my phone to the device show up unsolicited as it was received, but then it didn't seem to be stored anywhere.

The only thing I ever get back when I do the AT+CMGL is "OK". I tried pulling up individual ones using AT+CMGR=1-100 and got nothing back but "OK" I also tried changing where the "preferred storage" was using AT+CPMS, but couldn't make any headway.

```
AT
OK

at+CMGF=1
OK

OK
at+cmgs="4805554667"
> Outbound Test
> 
+CMGS: 193

OK

at+cmgl
OK

AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"Verizon",7

OK
AT+CMGR="193"
ERROR

AT+CMGR=193
+CMS ERROR: 321

AT+CMGR=1
OK
AT+CMGR=2
OK
AT+CMGR=3
OK

AT+CPMS?
+CPMS: "ME",0,100,"ME",0,100,"ME",0,100
OK

AT+CPMS=?
+CPMS: ("SM","ME"),("SM","ME"),("SM","ME")
OK

AT+CPMS=SM,SM,SM
+CPMS: 0,0,0,0,0,0
OK

AT+CPMS?
+CPMS: "SM",0,0,"SM",0,0,"SM",0,0
OK

at+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGL="ALL"
OK

at+CMGF=0
OK

AT+CMGL="ALL"
ERROR

AT+CMGL
OK

AT+CMGL=?
+CMGL: (0-4)
OK

AT+CMGL=0
OK

AT+CMGL
OK

at+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGL
OK

AT+CMGL=?
+CMGL: ("REC UNREAD","REC READ","STO UNSENT","STO SENT","ALL")
OK

AT+CMGL=ALL
OK
AT+CMGL="ALL"
OK

AT+CMGL="REC UNREAD"
OK

AT+CPMS=me
+CPMS: "ME",0,100,"ME",0,100,"ME",0,100
OK

+CMT: "4805554027","","17/11/15,18:42:11+00"
Incoming Test

AT+CSCS=?
+CSCS: ("GSM","IRA","8859-1","PCCP437","UCS2")
OK

AT+CSCS?
+CSCS: "IRA"
OK

AT+CSCS="GSM"
OK

AT+CMGL=ALL
OK

AT+CPMS?
+CPMS: "ME",0,100,"ME",0,100,"ME",0,100
OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the Telit firmware version that is on the Digi Xbee LTE Cat1 doesn't support storing incoming messages. Here is the response I got from Digi.

> The Telit LE866-SV1 modem running firmware version 23.00.002, does not
>   support SMS Storage within the modem. This is a known limitation of
>   that version of the Telit firmware which has been addressed in Telit
>   firmware version 23.00.004 for which Digi has not implemented yet.
>   When using the current version of the XBee Code installed with bypass
>   mode, you must configure the AT+CNMI to generate a +CMT notification
>   and handle the incoming message immediately as they arrive.
>
> So yes, with Telit firmware version 23.00.002, the AT+CMGL="ALL" will
>   be empty. At lest until we release a new version that includes the
>   updated Telit code.